# Use Boolean Criteria in AVERAGEIF()

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a column of classifications of how diverse counties in the US are and a column of Democratic Party vote share in the 2016 election. The diversity categories are "Very Diverse", "Somewhat Diverse", and "Homogeneous"

I'm trying to calculate the average vote share for "Very Diverse" counties and average vote share for everywhere else (so the criteria needs to be one of "Somewhat Diverse" or "Homogeneous".

Here is what I tried:

`=AVERAGEIF(raw_data!D:D,OR("Homogeneous","Somewhat Diverse"),raw_data!E:E)`

I got the `#DIV/0!` error. Can anyone help me fix that formula please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=AVERAGE(filter(raw_data!E:E, regexmatch(raw_data!D:D,"Homogeneous|Somewhat Diverse")))
```